# How to print using c#/wpf a single flowdocument in two copies in single sheet?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I would like to print a flowdocument which is receipt. Now this should be printed in two copies,but on single page. How to do that?

I have print page defined in XAML while i get values of particular items in code behind file. I want to print this in two copies, but on single document.

[image]

Comment: There are a number of options.  What might seem intuitive is, create a new `FlowDocument` and add your receipt to it twice.